# Not load res.partner in POS Odoo 8

Tags: odoo-8, point-of-sale

How to not load data res.partner in POS Odoo? Because row on the res.partner table is a lot and makes load POS so long. Thanks

Comment: So want do not want to load res.partner in POS like that because your POS is loading too much then either you can only load specific rows or else you can migrate module of pos_cache from v9 to v8.

Comment: If make limit show data, how to do?

Comment: Can describe furthermore your actual requirement and what you have done so far to achieve that.

Comment: I tried to load specific row with domain: function(self){ return [['customer','=',true],['write_uid','=',self.session.uid] in addons\point_of_sale\static\src\js\model.js . How to domain get date today? I have tried many ways

Comment: You want to get partners which are created on particular date.(In your case today) Like this ?

Comment: yes, so everyday res.partner table not show anything and load POS becomes faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing if **res.partners** are not that much necessary then do not load that in POS. Another way is apart from doing what you said you can create a check box in res.partner for allowing to load only checked partners in POS. Like in product.template there is a check box "**Available in POS**" which only allows to load product in POS which are checked from that box. Same you can do in res.partners. Only load that partners whoes checkbox is cheked.